# Python: Iterate through nested for-loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

My code is

```
num_list = [1, 2, 3]
alpha_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for number in num_list:
    print(number)
    for letter in alpha_list:
        print(letter)
```

and my output is:

```
Output
1
a
b
c
2
a
b
c
3
a
b
c
```

But I want to get Output like this:

```
 Output
    1
    a
    2
    b
    3
    c
```

How do I iterate through the nested for-loop to get the above mentioned output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip` for this.

```
num_list = [1, 2, 3]
alpha_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for number,letter in zip(num_list, alpha_list):
     print(number)
     print(letter)
```